# jQuery is(':visible') acting funny.

Tags: jquery, visible

I'm running into a strange problem with testing an object's visibility with jQuery.

I have this test JS:

```
alert($myObject.css('display'));
alert($myObject.is(':visible'));
```

The first alert displays 'block' which makes sense as firebug clearly shows that it is set to display: block and you can see the object on the page in the browser.

The second alert, though, displays 'false'. Which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Am I misunderstanding the use of is(':visible')?

Comment: can you give a sample of the code in jsfiddle? some more markup will help

Comment: Are you saying your element *is* visible on the page, but `.is(':visible')` is false? @KARASZI's answer is correct, but if your element is actually visible, this might be a different issue. Can you post a fiddle replicating the issue?

Comment: @j08691 if the object is set to display: block, and I can see it, I expect the is() statement to return TRUE in this case.

Comment: @nrabinowitz yes, that's the problem. I can see it on the page, I can see via firebug it has been set to display: block to make it visible, but yet the is statement returns false.

Comment: @DA - I don't think the answers below apply if you can actually see the element, but you'd have to post your HTML code to get an answer.

Comment: I'll try to pull the troublesome part out to show.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
    <div id="div2">
        <p>Some div content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
$myObject = jQuery('#div2');
alert($myObject.css('display')); // 'block'
alert($myObject.is(':visible')); // false
```

There are multiple reasons `$myObject` may not be visible, even though it has `display: none` style set. See [:visible selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) for details.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: except that I can see my object in the browser--its parent isn't hidden.

Comment: @DA.: Are you completely sure? Try to manipulate `$myObject` from using JavaScript (eg. set its border to red) and tell us if the result is as expected. If `$myObject` manipulation changes what you see in browser, then give us more details - try to narrow the problem by extracting the code that shows exact results, and show this code to us.

Comment: yep, already did the whole BORDER hack to see if it's the right object. I'll try to dismantle the page to see if I can find the source of the problem and post the markup.

Comment: Everyone gets credit for answer and I'll give you the answer. I've added my own answer to explain what happened by I'm too embarrassed to mark that the answer. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector is not equivalent with the `display` css property.

From the linked documentation, visible is `false` when:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Comment: Understood. None of those are true in this situation. It's set to display: block, it's not a hidden form element, it has no explicit height or width of zero and you can see it on the page (so it's ancestor does not appear to be hidden)

Comment: I'm looking forward to the jsFiddle link, I'm really curious about the cause of the problem.

Comment: I've added an answer explaining what happened. I'm a tad embarrassed. ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the [:visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) documentation:

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Check that none of these other conditions are true.

Answer (score 3):

So, the answer:

If someone else attaches a CLICK event to your object that you were previously unaware of, that event may be screwing up any logic you were trying to use. ;)

Alas, that's what happened here. Another click event had been attached to this object that was set to hide its parent. That was firing first--before my logic checked to see if it was visible.

In the end: user error.

There should be some form of reputation penalty when it's a user-error problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same issue. I solved it checking the **`.height()`** AFTER
>   the toggle call. Like this:

```
// detect jQuery toggle state
if ($('#toggled_element').height() > 0) {
    // do this, it's visible
}
else {
    // do this, it's not visible
}
```